# Split a repository into "sub-repositories" while retaining remote to a foreign repository

Tags: git, github, subdirectory

My main dev project is a "total conversion" of a game named NAEV. My TC is named **SoC** (short for "Stars of Call"), which is set in a totally different universe from NAEV, but uses the game source as-is. With my limited C abilities, I sometimes lend a hand to **NAEV**. It's written in C and **basically has two subfolders** : **src** (C source) and **dat** (XML/Lua data).

NAEV is stored on GitHub, in its repository named **naev/naev**, **which I do not own**. I have **my own clone** **Mutos/naev** on GitHub, which I keep in synch with naev/naev. For that, I use a local repository with **origin** pointing to Mutos/naev and **upstream** to naev/naev, like in https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/syncing-a-fork.

So I develop SoC by trying to keep up the source with NAEV and focusing on the data, which describes the SoC universe. So the issue is, that SoC must have the **same src** folder than NAEV, but a **totally different dat** folder.

For now, I synch by hand my SoC src folder with NAEV src folder. But that means I lose commits history and cannot gradually adapt my data according to the evolution of NAEV, commit by commit. So SoC is always trailing behind NAEV and each time I want to update SoC's src, I have a hard time adapting my data.

What I want is setting up a third repository for SoC, named Mutos/SoC, **whose src folder would follow NAEV src**, while its dat folder would be totally independant from NAEV's dat folder.

How can that be achieved ? Note that I'm not so skilled in GitHub, because I use it only occasionnally. So I'll need explanations to be worded for being understandable n00b-level ^-^

Thanks for any hint !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be what you're looking for, but you can consider:

1. Adding git submodules or...
2. Moving directories under same parent git directory

Go into an initialized git repo where you would want to store the other repos. Then, inside the same directory, use:

```
git submodule add <repo url>
```

For example,

```
git submodule add https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.git
```

You can find the repo url by going to the repo's main page and clicking "clone or download," then copy the link.

If these are not already git repos, then you cannot add these directories to the same git repo. Every directory you include needs to be a subdirectory of the git initialized directory. If they were, then you can use:

```
git add <directory path>
```

For example,

```
git add ./subdirectory1/subdirectory2
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for the answer.

The issue there is, that I just want to get the src folder in the naev/naev repo, which I don't own.

If I use the command you suggested, this would be :

git submodule add https://github.com/naev/naev

But it would create me a subfolder named naev in my own repo, with the whole naev/naev repo, which is not what I want.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the answer, I finally settled for submodules. I put my main repo with a subfolder named `Repositories` and subfodlers for `naev` and `SoC-dat` submodules.

I then had to devise a launcher script that either links or copies things around in an `Integration` subfolder of the main repo before launching the executable. Of that script, I have both a Linux (.sh) and a Windows (.bat) version. Making sure the `Integration` subfolder works correctly when switching system was the hardest. Finally, after execution, the script deletes everything in the `Integration` folder.

Comment: Under Linux, things are quite straightforward thanks to `ln -s`. Under Windows, however, there is no true equivalent, I could use `mklink /J` for folders, but had to `xcopy` files.